# PowerPoint: How to delete all blank text box at one time?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

### There are many text boxes with nothing inside in certain ppt file. How to delete all blank text box at one time?

Also, those blank text boxes reside not only one page of a file.

Comment: with CTRL+A, you can select _all_ boxes on a page, and then with CTRL+Click deselect the ones with text (clicking on the text itself). I doubt there is any better way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Select items for action \ deletion:  this can be done with ether CTRL-A or you can select items within a square box using your mouse (hold down the left button).  Then punch DEL

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to delete only the empty text boxes in PowerPoint, but you can use a macro instead.

1. Open your PowerPoint presentation and press **Alt+F11**. The VBA window will appear.
2. Insert -> Module
3. Copy&Paste the code below.

> Sub RemoveTextboxes()
>
> Dim SlideToCheck As Slide
>
> Dim ShapeIndex As Integer
>
> For Each SlideToCheck In ActivePresentation.Slides
>
> For ShapeIndex = SlideToCheck.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
>
> ```
>   If SlideToCheck.Shapes(ShapeIndex).Type = msoTextBox And _
>   Not SlideToCheck.Shapes(ShapeIndex).TextFrame.HasText Then
> ```
>
> SlideToCheck.Shapes(ShapeIndex).Delete
>
> End If
>
> Next
>
> Next
>
> End Sub

4. Go back to PowerPoint, go to Developer Tab (activate Developer Tab below), press Macros, select the RemoveTextboxes() and click Run.
5. Done! This will detele all the empty text boxes from your PowerPoint presentation.

---

**How make the Developer TAB appear**

1. File -> Options -> Customize Ribbon -> In the list of Main Tabs check the Developer box. DONE!